# Vuesjs 3 computed function in composition returns refImpl

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, computed-properties

i'm trying to use a computed function in Vuejs 3 externalized in a .js file using composition.

Here my .vue file, it's very simple : a count variable that is incremented to trigger the computed function.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ computedCount }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import useComputedValue from './js/useComputed' // Import computed function

const count = ref(0) // Instanciate the count variable
count.value += 1 // Trigger the compute
const computedCount = useComputedValue(count)
console.debug(computedCount)
</script>
```

And here is my useComputed.js file :

```js
import { computed } from 'vue'

export default function useComputedValue(count) {
  const computedValue = computed(() => count.value * 5)
  return {
    computedValue,
  }
}
```

The function simply mutliply the value given in parameter by 5.
The problem is that the console.log(computedCount) gives a

```js
{computedValue: ComputedRefImpl}
computedValue: ComputedRefImpl {dep: Set(1), _dirty: false, __v_isRef: true, effect: ReactiveEffect, _setter: ƒ, …}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

And in the template, it displays { "computedValue": 5 }
**So, the function doesn't return the value of the multiplied by 5 parameter, but a wrapper object refImpl.**

The exemple is adapted from the documentation : [Composition doc](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#standalone-computed-properties)

If I declare the computed function in the  tag in the .vue file directly without importing it from another file, it works well as expected : the function returns the count value multiplied by 5.

Obviously, that is something I don't understand clearly...but what ?

*I'm using 3.2 and the  tag, so the return from setup() in the script tag in no longer needed : [3.2](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3.2.html)*

Thank you in adavnce.

Comment: EDIT: it works well if I put the declaration of ```count```  in the useComputed.js file and export it.

Comment: I think it should be `const { computedCount } = useComputedValue(count)`. Or export it as `return computedValue` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Like this? It would help if you used `.value` to access the value of `computed`.
In the reactive object, accessing the ref object will directly return the .value attribute. The values accessed in the template syntax are all attributes of a reactive object, so .value is unnecessary. but in `console.log` it needs `.value`.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ computedCount }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import useComputedValue from './js/useComputed' // Import computed function

  const count = ref(0) // Instanciate the count variable
  count.value += 1 // Trigger the compute
  const { computedValue:computedCount } = useComputedValue(count)
  console.debug(computedCount.value)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the function itself. If you're outside of the template, you need to return `computedCount.value`

Answer (score 0):

because the function `useComputedValue` is returning an object of the form `{ computedCount: ComputedRef<number> }`  so vue and console.debug are working properly. all correct but it seems that what you are looking for is `computed` returned you will have 2 workarounds:

1. Edit file `./js/useComputed` (recommend this if you want the correct filename meaning)

```js
import { computed } from 'vue'

export default function useComputedValue(count) {
  const computedValue = computed(() => count.value * 5)
  // return {
  //  computedValue,
  //}
  return computedValue
}
```

2. Edit file `<vue>` (recommend this if you extend the function)

```js
<template>
  <div>
    {{ computedCount }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import useComputedValue from './js/useComputed' // Import computed function

const count = ref(0) // Instanciate the count variable
count.value += 1 // Trigger the compute
// const computedCount = useComputedValue(count)
const { computedValue: computedCount } = useComputedValue(count)
console.debug(computedCount)
</script>
```

Comment: demo: https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp1kctOwzAQRX9l5E1bSmNYsKmaCsSKPWLlTeo6rUtiW34EpCj/zth5KAGx83ged+bclrwYkzVBkD05eFGbqvDiyBTA4Syb9AB41bUJXpw/iiqIPbQt8PkPdF1qoGNHik7Be63gmVeSf+aMcB2U324ZGYaOcersizFzoLMlMHTcSuPBCR8M/sjaaOuhBStK6KC0uoYVbr+aUsGJxbpDTUZniezmVkApvPUt4zFQBsW91KjLFNfKxRQuCXmUWz9sUg9+F4pL3BD8VQwVTWFlcapE7MM4a5L0NofH2PNu5eUi7FCfxEaBPyhR7PcJ6zRzE+H0OBAEuSf9wbu6MHiPVmhgm+APCccIWtWzZgQZxZiRq/fG7Sl1JY+231ym7YXiK7MoImuRCVfvTlZ/OWFxMCNxBBrcoeSSISpOfkwMl6YwJb5TxVmURaj8hPi/I/uNR/hzMvkUr9cbyI89+YH0HTwhH0CffLBqPHsx4H68A+F1PylQCrM=